# C# string replace from position X to Y only

Tags: c#, vb.net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you perform string replacement on just a subsection of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087175/how-do-you-perform-string-replacement-on-just-a-subsection-of-a-string)

How to replace a string from position X to Y only, is there a string method?

input = ABCDXYZABCDXYZ

string replace input (start position = 3, end position=9, XYZ to PQR)

XYZ from position 3 to 9 should be replaced

output = ABCDPQRABCDXYZ

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a place for getting code - we would like to see the effort you already put into things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extension method that will create the method you described:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static string Replace(this string baseValue, int start, int length, string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        return baseValue.Substring(0, start) + baseValue.Substring(start, length).Replace(oldValue, newValue) + baseValue.Substring(start + length, baseValue.Length - (start + length));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
string result = str.Substring(0,3) + str.Substring(3, 6).Replace("XYZ", "PQR") + str.Substring(9);
```

Comment: This will not fulfill the requirements of the question. If you did this the output would not match what Fun Living asked for. You'd cut off a portion of the string instead of doing a replace on only a portion of it but returning the full string.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy Pridemore, Corrected and updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

String.Remove(start, count)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use Substring() to grab the piece of string you want to replace and then Replace(

```
myString = Substring(positionOne, lenghtOfString)
```

and then

```
finalString = Replace(myString, replacementString)
```